# Unable to run native-base component in react-native-web app

Tags: native-base, react-native-web

I am setting web app using the react native web. I want to use native base for the UI component but unable to use it in the web. I have followed this instruction https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink/tree/web-support

Since this official information regarding the library.

I web app is created using the following command 
yarn create react-app test-web --typescript

then added 
yarn add react-native@0.55.4 react-native-web@0.10.0 react
-art@16.8.2
yarn add -D @types/react-native@0.55.4

There is no babel config in my project then how can i fix this issue
[image]

my package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "test-web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.4",
    "customize-cra": "^0.2.12",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.1",
    "react-art": "16.8.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-web": "0.10.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-native": "0.55.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the plugin to your babel.config.js file within your mobile or app directory?

```
module.exports = {
     presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
     plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
};
```